# Is there a Java IDE that is not as complicated as Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I have just learned JAVA and am wanting to play around with it.  I keep seeing Eclipse repeated as the best IDE to write JAVA in.  I have been working with it and it appears to be much to complicated for what I am wanting to do.  I don't want multiple windows for multiple classes and functions.  Basically learning how to use write JAVA in Eclipse seems like an entire different language than the JAVA I learned.

I am simply looking for something similar to notepad that assists you with your code writing (adds ending brackets, color coded).

Please Help!!!

Comment: I use sublime text for simple things like that and its great. Sublime does cost money but a good free one is notepad++.

Comment: [**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/).

Comment: softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is better suited to these types of questions than stackoverflow.

Comment: You can write multiple classes in same class in eclipse or in any ide. But only one to be public class.

Comment: Emacs can be as simple or as complex as you wish. For Java as well.

Answer (score 3):

The most simple is Notepad++ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/
hope it fits your needs, its extreme in its simplicity, but works.
(and its free)

Answer (score 1):

Occupy a place for [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/3). Black background looks cooler.